# Simple Commerce Still Not Recording Purchases

Tags: paypal, simple-commerce

Okay, so I have rarely used Simple Commerce and I’m starting to see why. But the client’s needs are minimal so I don’t want to upgrade to a 3rd party addon.

I have setup Simple Commerce as specified including IPN. I have provided PayPal my public key, got my code, and also placed their provided cert, my public and private key in a directory above root accessible to EE. The temp folder for encrypted files, also above root, has read/write access. I have turned on Payment encryption in both Simple Commerce and in the PayPal account. I have providing PayPal the IPN URL from the CP.

Everything appears to work. The buttons are encrypted, the purchases are completed through PayPal no prob. I have debugging on and it shows the IPN notifications coming back in an email. I also used PayPal’s tester to test the IPN URL. I am buying as a logged in user. I have done everything the (limited) documentation says and yet, the purchases STILL won’t record in the db and fire off the appropriate emails.

Anyone have any insight?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked with the OP in ExpressionEngine support. In this case, it relates to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619982/ipn-verification-returns-invalid-as-paypal-is-sending-incorrect-charset-in-post

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23593082

Ensure that your IPN configuration is set to use UTF-8 encoding, or the Simple Commerce IPN verification will not be validated by PayPal.